# 2016 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2016 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://law.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 3):

## Democratise Law

You. Yes, you. Statistically*, just by actually reading this meta post, you're probably already likely to be a decent candidate for a moderator, and if not, you've probably already visited the election page. If you haven't done both of those things:

1. Head over to the [election page](https://law.stackexchange.com/election) and if you think you'd make a good moderator after reading through the information, nominate yourself!
   Even if you don't think you'd make a good moderator, you can comment on someone else's nomination if you think they'd make a good moderator.
2. Head over to the [question collection](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/496/58) and contribute a question for the moderator candidates, or vote for an existing question. (I'm seeing some very thoughtful questions there that really show how much people put into the community.)
3. Jump into the [election chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42673/2016-law-moderator-election) and discuss the election!
4. Don't forget to come back and vote for your future moderators!

Comment: Do you really want us to take your last piece of advice there?

Comment: @user6726 I call potential bias :P

Comment: @user6726 thanks. I may have been a little rushed. I mean. Ahem, it was all a test.